# dynamically reset observers on change Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, reactive

I have this small app.

I am dividing a dataframe in slices, using a previous and next button I am iterating showing the different slices of it in a datatable.

Inside the datatable I have checkboxes, their IDs are reset programmatically as soon as the new slice is requested.

From a tibble with 30 rows:

- I select the subset of it with a reactive value
- I define the checkboxes IDs
- I display the table
- I observe the inputs with lapply

the first display works, as soon as it changes I need a way to reset the observers.

sample code:

```
library("DT")
library("shinyjs")
library("tidyverse")
library("shiny")

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("prv", "prv", icon("arrow-left")),
  actionButton("nxt", "nxt", icon("arrow-right")),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  ###Sample Data
  mtcarsx <- reactive(
    data.frame(mtcars) %>%
      as_tibble() %>%
      mutate( slice=round(runif(row_number(),min=1,max=5))  ) 
  )
  
  ###Slice selector that will be modified with the button
  sliceN <- reactiveVal(1)
  
  ###Manipulating the slice
  thisSlice <- reactive({
    mtcarsx() %>%
      filter(slice==sliceN()) %>%
      mutate(rown=row_number()) %>%
      rowwise() %>% 
      mutate( 
        randmz=runif(row_number(),min=0,max=3),
        newvar=case_when(
          #I have checkboxes defaulted to true, checkboxes defaulted to false, checkboxes defaulted to true that I will disable
          randmz < 1 ~ as.character(checkboxInput(paste0("chk",rown),label="",value=TRUE)),
          randmz < 2 ~ as.character(checkboxInput(paste0("chk",rown),label="",value=FALSE)),        
          TRUE ~ as.character(checkboxInput(paste0("chk",rown),label="",value=TRUE))          
        ),
        mytype=case_when(
          #I have checkboxes defaulted to true, checkboxes defaulted to false, checkboxes defaulted to true that I will disable
          randmz < 1 ~ "MYTRUE",
          randmz < 2 ~ "MYFALSE",        
          TRUE ~ "DISABLED"          
        )
      )
  })
  
  #to disable checkboxes
  observe({
    print(input$chk1)
    n <- nrow(thisSlice())
    lapply(1:n, function(i){if(thisSlice()$mytype[i]=="DISABLED"){  shinyjs::disable(paste0("chk",i)) } })
  })
  
  #to listen to checkboxes
  observeEvent(input,{
    print(input$chk1)
    n <- nrow(thisSlice())
    lapply(
      1:n, 
      function(i){ 
        observeEvent(input[[paste0("chk",i)]],{
          print(paste0("chk",i))
          #print(input[[paste0("chk",i)]])
        })
      })   
  })
  
  
  
  #previous and next buttons
  observeEvent(input$nxt, {
    sliceN(sliceN()+ 1) 
  })
  observeEvent(input$prv, {
    sliceN(sliceN()- 1)
  }) 
  
  #display
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    #print(thisSlice())
    DT::datatable(thisSlice(), 
                  escape = FALSE, 
                  selection = 'none', 
                  rownames = TRUE, 
                  extensions = c('FixedColumns'),
                  options = list(searching = FALSE, 
                                 ordering  = FALSE,
                                 autoWidth = TRUE,
                                 scrollX = TRUE,
                                 FixedColumns = list(leftColumns = c(2)),
                                 preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                                 drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
                  ))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

how can I reset the observers when "next" is pressed and after the render of the datatable?

I also tried triggering the event after draw with a javascript callback like this:

```
  observeEvent(input$mycback,{
    print("received")
    o$destroy
    o
  })

o<-observeEvent(input,{
same as before
})
```

and in the dt callback

```
drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); Shiny.setInputValue("mycback","drawn", {priority: "event"})} '),
```

pasting the disable code inside my callback I've been able to call the disable function after redraw of the table successfully!! big success.

still the observers can listen for changes ONLY at the first draw, I can't explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are using the same ID for the `checkboxInput`, when you go back to the same slice. As the IDs have to be unique, it will only work the first time.  To overcome this issue you can add a counter value to the ID. Try this

```
library("DT")
library("shinyjs")
library("tidyverse")
library("shiny")

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("prv", "prv", icon("arrow-left")),
  actionButton("nxt", "nxt", icon("arrow-right")),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  cn <- reactiveValues(tr=1)
  ###Sample Data
  mtcarsx <- reactive(
    data.frame(mtcars) %>%
      as_tibble() %>%
      mutate( slice=round(runif(row_number(),min=1,max=5))  ) %>%
      mutate(rown=row_number())
  )

  ###Slice selector that will be modified with the button
  sliceN <- reactiveVal(1)

  ###Manipulating the slice
  thisSlice <- reactive({
    req(mtcarsx(),sliceN())
    print(cn$tr)
    if (sliceN() < 1 | sliceN() >5) return(NULL)
    df <- mtcarsx() %>% dplyr::filter(slice==sliceN()) %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(
        randmz=runif(row_number(),min=0,max=3),
        newvar=case_when(
          #I have checkboxes defaulted to true, checkboxes defaulted to false, checkboxes defaulted to true that I will disable
          randmz < 1 ~ as.character(checkboxInput(paste0("chk",rown,cn$tr),label="",value=TRUE)),
          randmz < 2 ~ as.character(checkboxInput(paste0("chk",rown,cn$tr),label="",value=FALSE)),
          TRUE ~ as.character(checkboxInput(paste0("chk",rown,cn$tr),label="",value=TRUE))
        ),
        mytype=case_when(
          #I have checkboxes defaulted to true, checkboxes defaulted to false, checkboxes defaulted to true that I will disable
          randmz < 1 ~ "MYTRUE",
          randmz < 2 ~ "MYFALSE",
          TRUE ~ "DISABLED"
        )
      )
    df
  })

  #to disable checkboxes
  observe({
    df <- thisSlice()
    print(input[[paste0("chk",df$rown[1],cn$tr)]])
    n <- nrow(df)
    lapply(1:n, function(i){
      print(paste0("chk",df$rown[i],cn$tr))
      if (df$mytype[i] == "DISABLED") {  shinyjs::disable(paste0("chk",df$rown[i],cn$tr)) }
    })
    
    lapply(1:n, function(i){ 
      thisval <- paste0("chk",df$rown[i],cn$tr) 
      observeEvent(input[[thisval]] ,{ 
        #print(input[[paste0("chk",df$rown[i],cn$tr)]]) 
        print(input[[thisval]]) 
      }) 
    }) 
  })

  #previous and next buttons
  observeEvent(input$nxt, {
    cn$tr <- cn$tr + 1
    sliceN(sliceN()+ 1)
  })
  observeEvent(input$prv, {
    cn$tr <- cn$tr + 1
    sliceN(sliceN()- 1)
  })

  #display
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    req(thisSlice())
    #if (sliceN() < 1 | sliceN() >5) return(NULL)
    DT::datatable(thisSlice(),
                  escape = FALSE,
                  selection = 'none',
                  rownames = TRUE,
                  extensions = c('FixedColumns'),
                  options = list(searching = FALSE,
                                 ordering  = FALSE,
                                 autoWidth = TRUE,
                                 scrollX = TRUE,
                                 FixedColumns = list(leftColumns = c(2)),
                                 preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                                 drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
                                 )
                  )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: hey YBS you are amazing. however it works for the disable part, still the observers don't work. building the nested observeEvent are not working properly, after the page switch it doesn't listen anymore.    lapply(1:n, function(i){
      thisval <- paste0("chk",df$rown[1],cn$tr)
      observeEvent(input$thisval ,{
        print(input[[paste0("chk",df$rown[1],cn$tr)]])
        print(input$thisval)
      })
    })

Comment: Prints fine for me.  Please see the updated code.

Comment: You are a king, thank you so much this was driving me insane. But is there a way to get rid of the old bindings? After 10 iterations I have an insane amount of stored inputs printing input.

Comment: I have not thought about it.

Comment: Thank you anyways, if you manage to find a solution, please come back with it, really appreciated and thanks for your efforts supporting the community :)